# Objective-C - Concatenating strings separated by pipes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, string-concatenation

I would like to loop through an array strings and add them to an `NSString` in the following way:

```
NSMutableArray *emailsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];

for (id email in emailsArray {
    NSString *emails = ??; 
}
```

So the final `NSString` should be the following:

```
NSString *emails = @"One|Two|Three";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `[emailsArray componentsJoinedByString:@"|"]` for this.

Sample:

```
NSMutableArray *emailsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];
NSString *emails = [emailsArray componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];
```

Here you'll have `emails = @"One|Two|Three"`.

Comment: Could you give me an actual code example of how to do this properly?

Comment: Maybe I don't really understand... but the point of using `componentsJoinedByString:` is not having to loop through the array.